# Problems connecting VBA to Access Database

Tags: vba, database-connection

I am using a VBA within a drafting program called MicroStation. The program just connects to an Access Database file to read data and return to MicroStation. The connection i have used for a while i got from connectionstrings.com was working but has since stopped. I can;t figure out what has changed apart from possible security settings, but all of the posts i have read do not seem to indicate this.

This is the previous connection string i used. If i google the issue, plus search StackOverflow 90% of the posts contain this connection string with no issues.

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" & sDBFullName & ";Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & sDBFullName & ";" & _
    "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & cPassword & ";Persist Security Info=False"
```

As the company had upgraded to Office 2016, i thought it might have been the connection string, so i found and used this updated one.

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" & sDBFullName & ";Uid=Admin;Pwd=pwd;"
```

When using the top connection string, MicroStation will simply crash with no error messages. If i use the second, i recieve the error message "Catastrophic Failure". When debugging i can narrow it down to the conn.open

Both of these connection strings work on multiple PC's, but wont work within the work environment.

So my question is. What could be causing these issues? What should i be on the lookout for? I am struggling to figure out why this is happening.
The user is able to read & write to the database using access, so i dont think its a permissions problem, it has been working fine in the past (but i cant get a straight answer as to what has changed)
I also went to the step of creating a simple VB.NET program to connect to the database and had no issues. Which leads me to rule out a corrupt database connector, or anything with Access. I am happy to post the whole module if it will help track down the issue.

Thanks in advance, i'm really confused with this issue!

Comment: The thing should be robust enough, but formally the semi-colon `;` is a _separator_, not a terminator. So `Pwd=pwd;"` is wrong and the last semi-colon should be removed.

Comment: What is the value of `sDBFullName`? Are you sure it does not contain reserved characters?

Comment: Could there be a 32-bit (MicroStation) versus 64-bit (Access 12.0 driver) problem?

Comment: Value of sDBfullname is correct. I did check but its just pathed to a server location, doesnt include any special characters or anything. The Access driver is 32 bit, ill check MicroStation tomorrow but im pretty sure its 32 bit aswell. Office is 32 bit.

Comment: I have checked and everything is 32bit except Windows

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with exactly same error in Microstation after IT upgraded Microsoft Office to 2016-32bit, last week.  I have finally been able to resolve it by installing Microsoft Sharepoint Designer 2013 for the users.  It makes the Microsoft.ACE.oledb.15.0 talk to ACCDB files again from Microstation SS-3/4/10 32Bit.